# How to get width and height of an image from Glide

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have set `<ImageView />` height to `wrap_content`. I am adding this layout in `recycler adapter`

There will be around `10 images` all images are set to `wrap_content`.

Is there any way to get the height of image rendered by Glide.

I am using this, but its returning the screen dimensions and not image `dimensions`.

```
 Glide.with(context).load(imgpth).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_loading)
                            .error(R.drawable.bg_loading).into(imageProdctBanner).getSize(new SizeReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSizeReady(int width, int height) {
                            Log.e("width","wdthheight "+width+"  :  "+height);

                        }
                    });
```

I need this to set height of recyclerView.

```
int totalItems= cardsRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=rvCards.getLayoutParams();
    params.height= heightOfImageView *totalItems;
    rvCards.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `onResourceReady()` method instead

```
Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
     .asBitmap()
     .load(path)
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                     Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
             int w = bitmap.getWidth();
             int h = bitmap.getHeight()
             mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working fine, does this return value in dp or px ?

Comment: @Kirmani88 in px ofcourse. As this answer solved the problem, you might as well accept it.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the info